# Event cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I try to get item value in data grid view with cell mouse click, but i get error message

> event cellmouseclick cannot be found

this is my code :

```
Private Sub gridview1_CellMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles GridView1.CellMouseClick

End Sub
```

can you tell me what happen with my code? i already find solution from internet, but i can't found it, thanks

Comment: select your gridview,goto Properties>events(a toolbox/settings icon).double click the event and add code

Comment: and whynot try events like CLICK or MOUSELRFTBUTTON CLICK?

Comment: @zackraiyan i can't found event CellMouseClick

Comment: @zackraiyan i can't found that in properties->events

Comment: use the rowdatabound event

Comment: @zackraiyan oh sorry, i will try again with it

Comment: It helps if you know what you're using. This question is tagged ASP.NET and yet you have code that uses a Windows Forms `DataGridView`.  Which is it?

Comment: The ASP.NET control has no such event. You have to differentiate between WinForms and ASP.NET when looking for solutions. The best is to check the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @jmcilhinney  that's my fault using windows form in web, i already get solution, thank